# Javascript button code only partially working

Tags: javascript, menu, submenu

Wondering if someone can tell me what I'm overlooking. I wrote the following javascript code that controls 9 menu buttons. When you click on each of the 9 buttons, submenu buttons display below the button you selected. When you click a different main menu button, the previous submenu buttons close (disappear) and new submenu buttons appear. Basically an accordion menu type.

Everything seems to work great, except I noticed that only 2 submenu buttons will display no matter what I try. Not sure why it won't show all the menus.

NOTE: I know this could be done easier with jquery but I wanted to experiment and practice my javascript, I'm a bit rusty.

The code:

```
    function SubMenu(Sub_Class_Name) {
var Z = document.getElementsByClassName(Sub_Class_Name);
var A = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button0');
var B = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button1');
var C = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button2');
var D = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button3');
var E = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button4');
var F = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button5');
var G = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button6');
var H = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button7');
var I = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button8');
var X ;
    for (X=0; X < Z.length; X++) {
if (A.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    A.item(X).style.display = 'none';
}
if (B.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    B.item(X).style.display = 'none';
}
if (C.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    C.item(X).style.display = 'none';
}
if (D.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    D.item(X).style.display = 'none';
}
if (E.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    E.item(X).style.display = 'none';
}
if (F.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    F.item(X).style.display = 'none';
}
if (G.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    G.item(X).style.display = 'none';
}
if (H.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    H.item(X).style.display = 'none';
}
if (I.item(X).style.display == 'block') { 
    I.item(X).style.display = 'none';
} 

    Z.item(X).style.display = "block";
}
```

}

EDIT: Not sure why its not letting me post the whole html code, but here's a link to a test site with the info. http://plentyoftales.com/vegas/Pages/testing.html

Comment: The HTML would be?Do you really have more than one `tips_button0` button?

Comment: Have you checked the console tab in the developer tools ? Is it giving any error ?

Comment: ugh, I thought I had saved the html too. For saving reason having a hard time with that. I just edited the original post to include a link to the testing site.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if have the same number of submenu buttons then it works fine. But if I have an uneven number of buttons then it doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

***Eureka!!***

Ok, for those following along at home or for those who stumble across this in the future looking for a solution (and I stress 'a solution' because there is no doubt another way or two to accomplish this), here is the problem and solution. I'm going to do my best to keep in short and understandable.

In my original code, I was trying to keep the function simple by doing everything in one function. In doing so I stumbled across an issue with the for loop of the function clinging to the class with the least number of array items.

In my case those I was using 9 main buttons that had several 'sub' buttons under each 'main' button. Each sub button collective under a main button had its on unique CSS class that I was trying to adjust the display style of (from none to block or vice versa). (fyi buttons could easily be div or another element).

So basically if I had several main button sections one with 6 sub buttons, another with 3 sub buttons, one with 5 sub buttons, and another with 4 sub buttons....the for loop would stop at 3 loops, thus never showing any buttons in excess of 3. Even if you told the loop to run to 1000 it would never go past 3.

I'm not sure exactly why that is, I just realized that the for loop stopped on the lowest number of class items. BTW if I had the same number of sub buttons in all sections, then it ran with no problem.

So the solution is to create a function with its own for loop, for each class of the sub buttons. And another for the opening of the current clicked button section. Then to simplify the calling of the functions, I created one function that called all the others. Not as simplistic as I originally wanted or thought but it's still simpler than calling all the element ID numbers and doing it that way.

More importantly it works.

Here's the revised javascript code:

```
function closeALL (Sub_Class_Name) {
close0();
close1();
close2();
close3();
close4();
close5();
close6();
close7();
close8();
SubMenu(Sub_Class_Name);
}
function close0 () {
var A = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button0');
var length = A.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       A[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
 }
 function close1 () {
var B = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button1');
var length = B.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       B[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
function close2 () {
var C = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button2');
var length = C.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       C[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
function close3 () {
var D = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button3');
var length = D.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       D[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
function close4 () {
var E = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button4');
var length = E.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       E[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
function close5 () {
var F = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button5');
var length = F.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       F[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
function close6 () {
var G = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button6');
var length = G.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       G[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
function close7 () {
var H = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button7');
var length = H.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       H[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
function close8 () {
var I = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button8');
var length = I.length;
var X
   for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
       I[X].style.display = 'none';
   }
}

function SubMenu(Sub_Class_Name) {
var Z = document.getElementsByClassName(Sub_Class_Name);
var X ;
    for (X=0; X < Z.length; X++) {  
    Z[X].style.display = "block"
}   

}
```

Here's the revised html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type='text/css'>
.tips_buttonholder {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 135px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.tips_buttons {
    float: left;
    width: 135px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tips_button0 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tips_button1 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tips_button2 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tips_button3 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tips_button4 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tips_button5 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tips_button6 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tips_button7 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tips_button8 {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script>

function closeALL (Sub_Class_Name) {
    close0();
    close1();
    close2();
    close3();
    close4();
    close5();
    close6();
    close7();
    close8();
    SubMenu(Sub_Class_Name);
}

function close0 () {
    var A = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button0');
    var length = A.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           A[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
function close1 () {
    var B = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button1');
    var length = B.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           B[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
function close2 () {
    var C = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button2');
    var length = C.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           C[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
function close3 () {
    var D = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button3');
    var length = D.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           D[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
function close4 () {
    var E = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button4');
    var length = E.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           E[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
function close5 () {
    var F = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button5');
    var length = F.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           F[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
function close6 () {
    var G = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button6');
    var length = G.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           G[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
function close7 () {
    var H = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button7');
    var length = H.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           H[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
function close8 () {
    var I = document.getElementsByClassName('tips_button8');
    var length = I.length;
    var X
       for (X=0; X < length; X++) {
           I[X].style.display = 'none';
       }
}

function SubMenu(Sub_Class_Name) {
    var Z = document.getElementsByClassName(Sub_Class_Name);
    var X ;
        for (X=0; X < Z.length; X++) {  
        Z[X].style.display = "block"
    }   

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="tips_buttonholder">
<!-- SECTION 4 START --> 
  <button id="main4" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button4'); ">HEALTH</button>

         <button class="tips_button4" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button> 
         <button class="tips_button4" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
         <button class="tips_button4" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button> 
<!-- SECTION 4 END -->  
<!-- SECTION 5 START --> 
  <button id="main5" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button5'); ">FOOD</button>

         <button class="tips_button5" type="button" onClick="">Discount Apps</button>
         <button class="tips_button5" type="button" onClick="">Buffets</button>
         <button class="tips_button5" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
<!-- SECTION 5 END -->  
<!-- SECTION 0 START -->  
  <button id="main0" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button0'); ">COMFORT</button>

       <button class="tips_button0" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button> 
      <button class="tips_button0" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
<!-- SECTION 0 END -->     
<!-- SECTION 1 START -->  
  <button id="main1" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button1'); ">MONEY</button>

         <button class="tips_button1" type="button" onClick="">Airport Rides</button>
         <button class="tips_button1" type="button" onClick="">Email Clubs</button>
         <button class="tips_button1" type="button" onClick="">Haggle</button>    

<!-- SECTION 1 END -->      
<!-- SECTION 2 START --> 
  <button id="main2" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button2'); ">TOURNAMENT</button>

         <button class="tips_button2" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
         <button class="tips_button2" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>

<!-- SECTION 2 END -->   
<!-- SECTION 3 START --> 
  <button id="main3" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button3'); ">GAMBLING</button>

         <button class="tips_button3" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
         <button class="tips_button3" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
         <button class="tips_button3" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
<!-- SECTION 3 END -->
<!-- SECTION 6 START --> 
  <button id="main6" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button6'); ">SITE SEEING</button>

         <button class="tips_button6" type="button" onClick="">Discount Apps</button>
         <button class="tips_button6" type="button" onClick="">Power Pass</button>
         <button class="tips_button6" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>  
<!-- SECTION 6 END --> 
<!-- SECTION 7 START --> 
  <button id="main7" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button7'); ">SHOPPING</button>

         <button class="tips_button7" type="button" onClick="">Discount Apps</button>
         <button class="tips_button7" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
         <button class="tips_button7" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
<!-- SECTION 7 END -->   
<!-- SECTION 8 START --> 
  <button id="main8" class="tips_buttons" type="button" onClick="closeALL('tips_button8'); ">ENTERTAINMENT</button>
  <button class="tips_button8" type="button" onClick="">Discount Apps</button>
         <button class="tips_button8" type="button" onClick="">Power Pass</button>
         <button class="tips_button8" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
  <button class="tips_button8" type="button" onClick="">Discount Apps</button>
         <button class="tips_button8" type="button" onClick="">Power Pass</button>
         <button class="tips_button8" type="button" onClick="">SubButton</button>
<!-- SECTION 8 END --> 
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```